# Matlab and Simulink Serial Communication

Tags: matlab, simulink, serial-communication

I need to open a serial COM port on Matlab, receive some data and then communicate on the same COM port in Simulink. However, it seems to be impossible to receive data in simulink since the COM port appears to be occupied by Matlab side.

Is it somewhat possible to receive data during a Simulink simulation from a port which has been already opened and set on matlab? If it is, how could I set this communication?

My idea is to transfer serial configuration information from Matlab workspace to the Simulink model (block?). How could I achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!